# Clear data object on route change

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a data object that contains color item (string), and It's associated with radio input, where I have v-model on t.

I have Add To Cart button, which I display conditionally in template using v-if - so if color wasn't selected, the button won't be visible, otherwise it would be.

The problem is that color always keep one value, and If I switch to another product it would keep the value from previous product, and button would be visible instantly.

Is there a way to clear color string after route changes - there is `$route.afterEach` but I'm not sure how to use it here.

Thanks.

Code:

```
<div class="Radio">
       <input 
          type="radio" 
          id="radio-{{ va.attributes.term_id }}" 
          name="variation" 
          value="{{ va.attributes.color_name }}" 
          v-model="color"
      >
      <label for="radio-{{ va.attributes.term_id }}"></label>
</div>
```

Stuff about buttons

```
<div v-if="color">
     <button @click="addToBag" class="Btn Btn--primary Btn--expanded">Add to Bag</button>
</div>
<div v-else>
     <button class="Btn Btn--primary Btn--expanded" disabled>Add to Bag</button>
</div>
```

There is data related to JS

```
data() {
  return {
    product: [],
    shared: State.data,
    color: ''
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add some code illustrating the issue

Answer (score 0):

1.user a global event bus in the entry js

```
window.eventBus = new Vue();
```

2.add a event handler to this color picker component , ie in ready()

```
ready(){   
    var vm = this  
    eventBus.$on('clearColorPicker', function(){vm.color = ''})
}
```

3.trigger the `clearColorPicker` event in $route.afterEach by

```
eventBus.$emit('clearColorPicker')
```

This can help you to trigger some change to certain component during route change.

**But I think In your case there is a better way like the changing of product trigger the color picker reset**

Comment: Thanks, but what should be eventBus ? 
I tried to clear input by setting it into addToBag method, It works but not solution that I need.It clear input for current product